# I can't install pillow in my venv with pip install Pillow

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library, zlib, msys2

I can't install pillow in my venv with pip install Pillow. This is the error message that I got.

```
Building wheel for Pillow (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for Pillow (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [199 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-39
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\BdfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\BlpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\BmpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ContainerIO.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\CurImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\DcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\DdsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\EpsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ExifTags.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\features.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\FitsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\FliImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\FontFile.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\FpxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\FtexImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\GbrImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\GdImageFile.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\GifImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\GimpGradientFile.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\GimpPaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\IcoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\Image.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageChops.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageCms.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageColor.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageDraw.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageDraw2.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageEnhance.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageFile.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageFilter.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageFont.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageGrab.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageMath.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageMode.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageMorph.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageOps.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImagePalette.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImagePath.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageQt.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageSequence.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageShow.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageStat.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageTk.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageTransform.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageWin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImtImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\IptcImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\JpegPresets.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\MicImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\MpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\MpoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\MspImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PalmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PcdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PcfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PdfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PdfParser.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PixarImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PsdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PSDraw.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PyAccess.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\QoiImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\SgiImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\SunImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\TarIO.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\TgaImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\TiffTags.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\WalImageFile.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\WebPImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\WmfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\XbmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\XpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\_binary.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\_deprecate.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\_tkinter_finder.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\_util.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\_version.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      copying src\PIL\__main__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
      running egg_info
      writing src\Pillow.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to src\Pillow.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to src\Pillow.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to src\Pillow.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no files found matching '*.c'
      warning: no files found matching '*.h'
      warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
      warning: no files found matching '*.txt'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.clang-format'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'renovate.json'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
      no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'wheels'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      writing manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      running build_ext
     
     
      The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
      a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
     
      Please see the install instructions at:
         https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
     
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 988, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-s3czzkka\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 103, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-s3czzkka\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-s3czzkka\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-s3czzkka\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-s3czzkka\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 989, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-s3czzkka\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-s3czzkka\normal\Lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 369, in run
          self.run_command("build")
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-s3czzkka\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-s3czzkka\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 989, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-s3czzkka\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-s3czzkka\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 131, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-s3czzkka\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-s3czzkka\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 989, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-s3czzkka\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-s3czzkka\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 88, in run
          _build_ext.run(self)
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-s3czzkka\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 345, in run
          self.build_extensions()
        File "<string>", line 811, in build_extensions
      __main__.RequiredDependencyException: zlib
     
      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
     
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Fitness_store\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Fitness_store\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Fitness_store\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
          return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-effsyhwi\pillow_4d0dd3bf95644f85a6a8bded18a32784\_custom_build\backend.py", line 53, in build_wheel
          return super().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings, metadata_directory)
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-s3czzkka\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 434, in build_wheel
          return self._build_with_temp_dir(
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-s3czzkka\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 419, in _build_with_temp_dir
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-effsyhwi\pillow_4d0dd3bf95644f85a6a8bded18a32784\_custom_build\backend.py", line 47, in run_setup
          return super().run_setup(setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-s3czzkka\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 1005, in <module>
      __main__.RequiredDependencyException:
     
      The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
      a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
     
      Please see the install instructions at:
         https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
     
     
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for Pillow
Failed to build Pillow
ERROR: Could not build wheels for Pillow, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects**your text**
```

I tried to install zlib through MSYS2 in my venv and then to install willow, because that's what the mistake says it's missing, but I encountered the same error message without any success. I'm with 64 bit system.

Comment: did you try to upgrade the pillow and pip packages ?

Comment: Hmm normally pillow should come with 64bit binaries also on windows. Do you use an outdated python version by any chance? Also see https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#basic-installation

Comment: try `python -m pip install Pillow`

Comment: It seems it tries to compile C/C++ code and it shows `The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,` - maybe it needs source code for `zlib` (C/C++) or at least files with heades. On Linux it would need to install system package with postfix `-dev` (development) but I don't know what you need on WIndows. Maybe you find precompiled module.

Comment: Any specific reason you’re trying to build from source?  Notoriously tricky on Windoze. As mentioned … a [pre-compiled binary wheel](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/#files) might be easier.

Comment: Try this `py -m pip install Pillow --upgrade`
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in 
tkhtmlview 0.2.0 requires Pillow<10.0.0,>=9.4.0, but you have pillow 10.1.0 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed Pillow-10.1.0

Answer (score 2):

You say you're on a 64-bit system, but do you have a 32-bit version of Python installed?

From Pillow 10, precompiled 32-bit wheels are no longer provided:

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/releasenotes/10.0.0.html#bit-wheels

pip is therefore trying to build from source, and you don't have the necessary dependencies.

Options:

- Install a 64-bit version of Python: https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/
- Install `pillow<10`
- Install dependencies to build from source: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#building-from-source

Comment: Thank you so much. It was a long struggle. I installed pillow<10 and everything works perfect. I tought it will be a more difficult to install pythob 64-bit version, because potentially can harm my project and I have to recreate my venv, so I sticked to the second option.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the raspi-2. As it's 32bit, I had issues even when I reverted to a version <10. The following approach worked for me

```bash
sudo apt-get install libtiff5-dev libjpeg-dev libopenjp2-7-dev zlib1g-dev libfreetype6-dev liblcms2-dev libwebp-dev tcl8.6-dev tk8.6-dev python3-tk libharfbuzz-dev li
bfribidi-dev libxcb1-dev

python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow --no-binary :all:
```

NOTE: it took a while to build